# How to pass angular's data-ng-repeat current iterator $index to MVC helper Html.Partial()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I want to pass the index of current iterator when doing angulars data-ng-repeat.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="store in model.storeList">
 <div>... not relevant ...</div>
 @Html.Partial("Stores", Model.StoreList[@: $index])
</div>
```

The above doesn't work. 
My real code is much more complicated, therefore I cannot change the code to use razor's foreach.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use an asp.net partial view inside a Javascript, angular ng-reapt? ofc it wouldnt work, all it would do is repeat the code that was generated by the server side code

Comment: No, I'm using angular ng-repeat inside Asp.net mvc View

Comment: not what i meant..., asp.net is server side code, angular is client side, the ng-repeat loop only iterates the code that was generated by the server side, in your case you are trying to pass the `$index` value to a server side method, this wont work...